# How to a partition a SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd

including moving files, and with minimum writing (WHich is bad for a SSD)

It seems most tools I use do no allow it, or I need to move data first, and the tools I would use doesn't let me.  (I do partially understand the reason).

Sat: Standard Windows shrink lets me do some shrinking, but not very much compared to free space, and not always.
Its a Windows Surface Pro 4, but USB based tools are OK.

(I know how to partition, the question is about partitioning SSD, or possibly related issues related to Windows 10/Surface Pro)

References:
http://www.howtogeek.com/170752/htg-explains-should-you-use-an-ssd-optimization-utility/

Comment: Writing to an SSD isn't "bad", and it's not going to wear the drive out in any meaningful way.  Stop worrying about writing to it. :)

Comment: You partition a SSD exactly like how you partition a HDD.

Comment: @OP: you are right that writing to an SSD is bad. If you write a lot for a few decades then it might die. Personally I do not tend to worryt about it. Most of my disks (and future SSDs) will et replaced within 10 to 20 years.

Comment: Normal defragmentation is a lot of writing, and doesn't improve performance on an SSD.  I have the impression the standard Windows shrink, wont shrink because there is data where I want to shrink it, and I don't know exactly how to "just more the data" and the end.

Comment: Then just defrag it. It is not that bad to do if you have TRIM enabled. Just do not run it every hour for the rest of your life. But once is not bad except if you have the very first generation of SDs. Modern SSDs can handle it.

Comment: TRIM looked promising, but its not about TRIMming space from the end:

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/170752/htg-explains-should-you-use-an-ssd-optimization-utility/

Comment: No, TRIM is used to negate most of the 'bad' effects of writing to a SSD. TRIM ebaled means performance should not degrade over time.

Comment: How to partition a SSD, how can this be unclear.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem, you have a large partition and want to re-partition the space it occupies into two or more partitions.

Example: you have a 100 GB partition and want to split it up into a 60 GB and a 40 GB partition.

The important question is, how much data is used right now (how full is your partition right now?). If you use more then 60 GB, you need to use an external drive to temporarily store your data. If you use less, you can do it.

There are many tools that can do this, I made good experience with [Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html). The free version is good enough.

Just select resize, and set it to 60 GB and thats it. If necessary, the tool will copy some files around (the ones that are in places where the other partition will be). 
After the resize is done, you have 40 GB of free space that you can re-partition.

Comment: I have partitioned disks many times, the issue is with it being an SSD.

Comment: What is the issue? If your new parition layout ranges from 0 to 60% of the blocks, you have to move the data between 60% and 100% of the blocks. There is no way around this. But at least the data in the first 60% will not be moved.

Comment: How does it being a SSD change how you partition it?

Comment: There is only one SSD/HDD difference - the SSD has to be aligned.

Comment: So does a HDD, though you want to align a HDD on 4K boundaries and a SSD on a larger boundary (depending on the flash chips). But other tha that it is indeed the same.

Comment: @masgo; How do I just move the data?

Comment: (SO you don't understand my problem :-)

Comment: As I told in my answer, Parition Master does move the data around when you just resize the partition.

Answer (score -1):

Whether it's an SSD or HDD is irrelevant.  You can partition both equally.

gparted is absolutely fantastic.  You can boot into it by installing yumi onto a boot usb and then choosing to install gparted using yumi.  you can then boot into yumi and partition to your heart's content.

Pingers

Comment: The tools I have tried won't let me.  (So it is not "irrelevant") - it could be something about the way it is formatted though).

Comment: I mean partitioning software does not know or care whether it is an ssd or HD!  It partitions both equally. If it won't partition your SSD, then you likely have a fault with your ssd